# Ho can I suppress background circle overlapping the rectangle while doing minAreaRect detection in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, shapes, malformed

The overlapping nozzle-tip behind the SMD device extends the minAreaRect by the overlap ... see [WebCam snapshot with detected rectangle area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KEiV.png).

My current proccessing pipline is ...

```
<cv-pipeline>
   <stages>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.ImageRead" name="0" enabled="true" file="C:\Users\kk\.openpnp\org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.ImageWriteDebug\Neuer Ordner (2)\bv_source_6696231034193164089.png"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.ImageWriteDebug" name="13" enabled="true" prefix="bv_source_" suffix=".png"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.BlurGaussian" name="10" enabled="true" kernel-size="7"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.MaskCircle" name="4" enabled="true" diameter="200"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.ConvertColor" name="1" enabled="true" conversion="Bgr2HsvFull"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.MaskHsv" name="2" enabled="true" hue-min="200" hue-max="255" saturation-min="0" saturation-max="255" value-min="0" value-max="255"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.ConvertColor" name="3" enabled="true" conversion="Hsv2BgrFull"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.ConvertColor" name="6" enabled="true" conversion="Bgr2Gray"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.Threshold" name="12" enabled="true" threshold="100" auto="false" invert="false"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.FindContours" name="5" enabled="true" retrieval-mode="ConnectedComponent" approximation-method="None"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.FilterContours" name="9" enabled="true" contours-stage-name="5" min-area="50.0" max-area="900000.0"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.MaskCircle" name="11" enabled="true" diameter="160"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.DrawContours" name="7" enabled="false" contours-stage-name="9" thickness="2" index="-1">
         <color r="255" g="255" b="255" a="255"/>
      </cv-stage>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.MinAreaRect" name="result" enabled="true" threshold-min="100" threshold-max="255"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.ImageRecall" name="14" enabled="true" image-stage-name="0"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.DrawRotatedRects" name="8" enabled="true" rotated-rects-stage-name="result" thickness="2" draw-rect-center="true" rect-center-radius="20" show-orientation="true"/>
      <cv-stage class="org.openpnp.vision.pipeline.stages.ImageWriteDebug" name="15" enabled="true" prefix="bv_result_" suffix=".png"/>
   </stages>
</cv-pipeline>
```

Unfortunately there is no access to `approxPolyDP`

What is a good solution to suppress/filter-out this extension caused by the nozzle-tip?